# Unable to run swirl()

Tags: r, swirl

Unable to start swirl.

I have already installed and loaded swirl package.

```
> install.packages("swirl")
> library("swirl")
> swirl()
```

Written below is the error i'm getting

```
> swirl()
Error in match.arg(type, c("success", "failure", "error", "skip","warning")) : 
     'arg' must be NULL or a character vector

| Leaving swirl now. Type swirl() to resume.
```

Here is my sessionInfo()

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.4 (2016-03-10)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X 10.10.4 (Yosemite)

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] swirl_2.4.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] httr_1.1.0      magrittr_1.5    R6_2.1.2        tools_3.2.4     RCurl_1.95-4.8  curl_0.9.7      yaml_2.1.13     memoise_1.0.0   crayon_1.3.1    stringi_1.0-1  
[11] stringr_1.0.0   digest_0.6.9    testthat_0.11.0 bitops_1.0-6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 # Temporary solution found on the link provided below the code
 install.packages("remotes")
 library(remotes)
 install_github("swirldev/swirl[stable]")
 library(swirl)
 swirl()
```

For more information, please visit here: this:https://github.com/swirldev/swirl/issues/429